# Getting element with no attributes using Jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I have the following html, using Jsoup I'm trying to extract the text in the p section which does not have any attributes (the text "Some text 2" and not "Some text 1").

```
<div id="intro">
    <h1 class="some class">
    <p id="some_id">
        Some text 1
    </p>
    <p>
        Some text 2
    </p>
</div>
```

I tried using the following Jsoup expression:

```
div[id=intro] > p:not(:has(@*))
```

But it doesn't work.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: how about `"div#intro p:not(#some_id)"` it will select second p but only in your case, it doesn't say all p's with no attribs at all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can use the [JSOUP CSS selector](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) `p:not([^])`, which would select any p that does not match having an attribute starting with anything.

```
String html = "<div id=\"intro\">"
        + "<h1 class=\"some class\">"
        + "<p id=\"some_id\">"
        +   "Some text 1"
        + "</p>"
        + "<p name=\"some_name\">"
        +   "Some text A"
        + "</p>"
        + "<p data>"
        +   "Some text B"
        + "</p>"
        +"<p>"
        +   "Some text 2"
        +"</p>"
        +"</div> ";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements els = doc.select("p:not([^])");
for (Element el:els){
    System.out.println(el.text());
}
```

the above example will only print out

```
Some text 2
```

because only this p element has no attributes.

Note that the selector `p[^]` will pick all p elements that do have an attribute.